# Why this .htaccess rewrite code isn't redirecting properly?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, web-development-server

It gets stuck in endless redirect loop. If in the last RewriteRule I use END instead of L it works as intended. Why is it acting this way and is there any other way to fix it?

```
RewriteEngine on

#remove tailing slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/+$ /$1 [R,L]

#external redirect: /page.php to /page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /$1 [R,L]

#internal redirect: page to page.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ $1\.php [L]
```

My Apache version is 2.4.43

---

SOLUTION:

I think I understand now what actually happened. Mod_rewrite works only on one version of URI and changes are only visible in browser when I use R flag. That together with @anubhava's answer is what caused endless redirect loop. In other words I thought that `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /$1 [R,L]` and `RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ $1\.php [L]` don't actually work on same version of URI.

R flag explained:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r

Comment: Your last rule `RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ $1\.php [L]` will redirect any url to that url + `.php`. So you'll get urls that look like this: `index.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php` and it the URL will continue to rewrite itself, infinitely. The `[L]` flag doesn't mean _this should be the last rule ever to execute_. It means _this is the last rule to execute before going back to the beginning and starting again_.

Comment: What is your Apache version?

Comment: Doesn't `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f` help with that?

Comment: Apache 2.4.43-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flags `L` and `END` behave differently. `L` flag means rune the rewrite loop again (that acts like `continue` in a while loop) and `END` loop terminates the loop (that acts like `break` in a while loop).

`END` flag was introduced in Apache 2.4 and it is used to prevent rewrite looping as you are currently observing.

When you use `L` then your last rule adds `.php` at the end of request uri and when rewrite loop runs again `#external redirect` rule removes `.php` from request uri and then again last rule adds `.php` at the end of request uri. This loop continues and causes infinite looping. To prevent this you can use `END` flag in last rule that just terminates mod_rewrite execution for current request and prevents looping behavior.

[Check: mod_rewrite ruleset processing](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html#InternalRuleset)

Comment: But my last rule only serves .php file it doesn't change request URI, or does it? Each of my rewrite blocks work fine on there own but combination of second and third produces error. I am aware that the mod_rewrite engine cycles through .htaccess file and I know what END and L flags do.

Comment: It does change request uri

Comment: How does it change URI if address bar stays the same in browser when I test only last code block? I thought that changing the URI will result in change in user's address bar or is that what R(edirect) flag does?

Comment: @HerculePoirot: Request URI doesn't change in your browser because there is no external redirect in last rule however internally it does change within `mod_rewrite` execution. If you enable `RewriteLog` then Apache will log it before applying each rule.